# Similar commands to %temp%

Tags: windows, command-line

Are there any other commands similar to the %temp% command in windows.

For example is there one for My documents or application data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%TEMP%` is not a command, it is an environment variable. To see all your environment variables, execute the `set` command. Among others, you should see `USERPROFILE` whose value is the directory above `My Documents`. You can also execute `set /?` to read more about the `set` command.

Comment: The `My Documents` folder is not necessarily in the `%USERPROFILE%` folder. That may be the default location, but on all my systems it's been moved, usually to something like `D:\My Documents in an effort to keep it off of the operating system's volume. The path to its current location is stored in the registry and is not available in any environment variables AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

`%TEMP%` is not a command; it's an [environment variable](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Environment_variable). See [this list](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Environment_variable#Examples_from_Microsoft_Windows) for some examples for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

There are [lists of](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm) [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows) too.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no standard system-defined environment variable containing the path to the current user's`My Documents`folder for you to use.

However, since it is stored in the Windows registry, its value can be copied into an environment variable of you own making using the batch file commands I found shown below -- taken from this old [web post](http://archive.slickdeals.net/showpost.php?s=0738bbc74caff68b704cb0a1fb310a1f&p=5601223&postcount=4) by @eibgrad which places it into one named`%my_docs%`:

```
set reg_key="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
set reg_val="Personal"
set reg_query='reg query %reg_key% /v %reg_val%'
for /f "eol=; skip=4 tokens=3*" %%i in (%reg_query%) do set my_docs=%%i %%j
if "%my_docs:~,13%" == "%%USERPROFILE%%" set my_docs=%USERPROFILE%%my_docs:~13%
echo %my_docs%
```

I added an extra line at the end to print out the value found.